# Need help to express the Taylor series for $\coth(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am finding a way to find the general formula for the series expansion of $\dfrac{x}{2}\coth\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$. I know that this is the generating function of even Bernoulli numbers. Its general formula is

$$\dfrac{x}{2}\coth\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{B_{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

In order to prove this formula, I wish to first find the formula for $\coth(x)$. Looking on wikiproof, I find [this site](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Series_Expansion_for_Hyperbolic_Cotangent_Function):

I am going to copy the proof here, and wish to ask the questions based on the numbered line of the proof

$$\coth(x)=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}\tag{1}$$

Multiply denominator and numerator for $e^{x}$, we have

$$\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{e^{2x}-1+2}{e^{2x}-1}=1+\frac{2}{e^{2x}-1}\tag{2}$$

Factor $\dfrac{1}{x}$ out, we have

$$1+\dfrac{1}{x}\left(\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}\right)\tag{3}$$

It is known and without proving here that $\dfrac{x}{e^{x}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{B_nx^{n}}{n!}$, substituting $2x$ and draw out the constant $2$, we have:

$$1+\dfrac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{B_{n}(2x)^{n}}{(n!)}\right)\tag{4}$$

The next step is to "release" the first two terms of the infinite series from the sigma notation chunk, with $B_{0}=1$ and $B_{1}=-\dfrac{1}{2}$, the first two terms are $1$ and $-x$

$$1+\dfrac{1}{x}\left(1-x+\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\dfrac{B_{n}(2x)^{n}}{n!}\right)=1+\dfrac{1}{x}-1+\dfrac{1}{x}\left(1-x+\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\dfrac{B_{n}(2x)^{n}}{n!}\right)=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\dfrac{B_{n}(2x)^{n}}{n!}\right)\tag{5}$$

Convert the index from $n=2$ to $n=1$ in the sigma notation and change the index $n$ to $2n$ in the $B_n$ of the above equation to include all even Bernoulli numbers, we have:

$$\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{B_{2n}(2x)^{2n}}{2n!}\right)\tag{6}$$

Now, here is my question, the next step is to change the of the sigma notation from $n=1$ to $n=0$. So why wikiproof writes as followed:

$$\dfrac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{B_{2n}(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\tag{7}$$

Is this the intermediate step that is left out by wikiproof?, we need to minus the $B_0x^{2\cdot0}=1$:

$$\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x}\left(-1+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{B_{2n}(2x)^{2n}}{2n!}\right)\tag{8}$$

As with $(5)$, if you increase the summation index, you release more terms. So if you decrease the index, you should, and this is my guess, eliminate terms to avoid adding duplicated terms. Is this interpretation correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are completely correct. The general principle is the following (as you have noted):
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=(-a_0+a_0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=-a_0+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$

---

You confused yourself. Line $(5)$ should look like this:

\begin{align*}
1+\frac1x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n(2x)^n}{n!}\right)
&=1+\frac1x\left(\color{blue}{1-x}+\sum_{\color{red}{n=2}}^\infty\frac{B_n(2x)^n}{n!}\right)
\\
&=1+\color{blue}{\frac1x-1}+\frac1x\left(\sum_{\color{red}{n=2}}^\infty\frac{B_n(2x)^n}{n!}\right)
\end{align*}

This is perfectly in sync with what the ProofWiki writes as:

$$1+\frac1x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n(2x)^n}{n!}\right)=\frac1x+\frac1x\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{B_n(2x)^n}{n!}\right)$$

The later index shift relies on the same principle as you have noted correctly (and as I have mentioned above).

Comment: If you look at $(5)$, after releasing 2 terms, the second is eliminated, but the first term, which is $1$, still remains, am I correct?

Comment: @JamesWarthington Yes. However, you (or your reference) made a confusing typo: the $1-x$ within the paratheses after the first equality are wrong.

Comment: @mrtauho: But if this is the case, it makes the proof of wikiproofs collapse, don't you think?

Comment: @mrtauho: So what should it be instead of $1-x$. I think I am still correct, I mistype the formula before converting the index from $n$ into $2n$ to include all even Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: @JamesWarthington I added a short clarification regarding your typo in line $(5)$. I hope everything is clear now.